# Creating class objects error: TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, class, object, typeerror

I am trying to make a Library class object which has 2 methods:

1. List item a method to add Books to Library object
2. List item a **str** method which prints all the books held by the library.
   However, when i run use my Library methods I get the error: "TypeError: **init**() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given."

Here is the code for creating the book object:

```
class book():
    def __init__(self,title="",author="",genre="",grade_level=0,pages=0):
        self.title=title
        self.author=author
        self.genre=genre
        self.grade_level=grade_level
        self.pages=pages

#str method to the Book class        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"The book {self.title} by {self.author} is a {self.genre} book for {self.grade_level} grade."
```

Here is the code for creating the Library object along with it's function:

```
class library:
    def __init__():
        self.library=[]

    def add(self,book):
        self.library.append(book)

    def __str__(self,book):
        temp = ""
        for book in self.library:
            temp = temp + str(book(i['title'],i['author'],i['grade_level'],i['pages'])) + "\n"
#             print(book(i['title'],i['author'],i['grade_level'],i['pages']))
            return temp
```

Here are the books I am adding to the library:

```
**books =** [
    {
        "title": "The Hunger Games",
        "author": "Suzanne Collins",
        "genre": "Science Fiction",
        "grade_level": 7,
        "pages": 374
    },
    {
        "title": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
        "author": "J.K. Rowling",
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "grade_level": 5,
        "pages": 309
    }]
```

Here is the code I am running to add books to the library:

```
my_library = library()
my_library.add(books)
print(my_library)
```

which results in the error:
TypeError: **init**() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hint: see where the code says `def add(self,book):`? What is the purpose of `self` here? What would happen if it were removed? Do you see how the same reasoning applies to `__init__`?

Comment: self refers to the library item it self. So if when using a method with dot notation in code: my_library.add(list_of_books), 'self' in the method code would refer to 'my_library'.

```
I tried removing it too, and got the below error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
      1 my_library = library()
----> 2 my_library.add(books)
      3 print(my_library)

TypeError: add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given ```

Comment: Right, so. Notice how, when you took `self` away from the place where it made sense to have `self`, it *caused the same kind of error to happen* in that place? So, the logical conclusion is that there **should** be `self` in that place, right? Now, I just finished explaining to you how the two places *work the same way*, right? Therefore....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `self` in the `__init__` method.

When you run `my_library = library()`, `my_library` is actually passed as an argument to `__init__`. It is the name of the instance of the class `library`. But you defined `__init__` as a method taking no argument, so here is the problem.

Comment: Added self to the __init__ argument:
class library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.library=[]

and it pushes the __str__ argument, and give the error: TypeError: __str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'book'.

Comment: Yes, this time you only need `self` as argument of `__str__`. In your code, you already don't use `book` because redefined it as an element of `self.library`. After you corrected this bug, you still have a bug in your for loop but I'll let you think about it.